# Generating reports for different time zones in Java

Tags: java

as a part of my requirement,I have to fire a SQL query which takes yesterday's midnight and today's midnight in the respective time zone as input.Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What does "respective time zone" mean? Whose time zone? Your Question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Use ZonedDateTime:

```
    String DATE_FORMAT = "dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss a";
    String dateInString = "22-1-2015 10:15:55 AM";
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateInString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT));

    ZoneId singaporeZoneId = ZoneId.of("Asia/Singapore");
    System.out.println("TimeZone : " + singaporeZoneId);

    //LocalDateTime + ZoneId = ZonedDateTime
    ZonedDateTime asiaZonedDateTime = ldt.atZone(singaporeZoneId);
    System.out.println("Date (Singapore) : " + asiaZonedDateTime);

    ZoneId newYokZoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
    System.out.println("TimeZone : " + newYokZoneId);

    ZonedDateTime nyDateTime = asiaZonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(newYokZoneId);
    System.out.println("Date (New York) : " + nyDateTime);

    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT);
    System.out.println("\n---DateTimeFormatter---");
    System.out.println("Date (Singapore) : " + format.format(asiaZonedDateTime));
    System.out.println("Date (New York) : " + format.format(nyDateTime));
```

Output is:

```
TimeZone : Asia/Singapore
Date (Singapore) : 2015-01-22T10:15:55+08:00[Asia/Singapore]
TimeZone : America/New_York
Date (New York) : 2015-01-21T21:15:55-05:00[America/New_York]

---DateTimeFormatter---
Date (Singapore) : 22-1-2015 10:15:55 AM
Date (New York) : 21-1-2015 09:15:55 PM
```

Use the methods from here to get what you need

Example taken from: [Java – Convert date and time between timezone](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-convert-date-and-time-between-timezone/)

Comment: ,you have taken a sample date but I have to take midnight as reference.

Comment: Midnight of which Timezone? If the case is with the target timezone - you got all figured out - set the dateInString to be 22-1-2015 00:00:00 AM and use the 'singaporeTimeZoneID' as the target TZ, then use yours instead of NewYork.
If It's the other way around, you want to check when is YOUR midnight in each time zone, set singaporeZoneId as your timezone and newYorkZoneId as the target

Answer (score 0):

simply run your cronjob at every hour and generate only the reports in which timezones the day just ended

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

Use a driver compliant with JDBC 4.2 or later, running on Java 8 or later, to benefit from use of the modern java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

Determining "today" and "yesterday" means determining a date. Determining a date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
LocalDate yesterday = today.minusDays( 1 ) ;
```

To query for timestamps in the database, we need specific moments. The Question specifies midnight. The term "midnight" is vague. Let's use "first moment of the day" instead.

Never assume the day starts at 00:00:00. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) mean it may start at another time such as 01:00:00. Let java.time determine first moment of the day.

```
ZonedDateTime start = yesterday.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Generally, the best approach to defining a span of time is though the Half-Open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So we want to start at first moment of one day and run up to, but not include, the first moment of the *next* day.

```
ZonedDateTime stop = today.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

In Half-Open, we do *not* use the SQL command `BETWEEN`.

SQL

```
SELECT * FROM t 
WHERE event >= ? AND event < ? ;
```

Java

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , start ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , stop ) ;
```

To retrieve the timestamps, use `getObject`.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( "event" , Instant.class ) ;
```

To move from UTC to a zone, apply a `ZoneId`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```